# ¿Como imprimo las variables de una estructura en forma de arreglo en C++?

Tags: c++

Hola me gustaría saber si es posible manipular una estructura de datos como si fueran vectores, me cuesta un poco explicarlo. Si por ejemplo yo tengo un arreglo char Arreglo[10], puedo imprimir en consola cada uno de sus caracteres con un ciclo for, pero no se como hacer eso para imprimir el valor de de cada variable de una structura.

```
struct Strings {
string Cadena1 = "String 1";    
string Cadena3 = "String 2";
string Cadena4 = "String 3";
string Cadena5 = "String 4";
}s;
```

intenté esto pero no funcionó, con i intenté representar las variables contenidas en la estructura

```
for(int i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
    cout << s[i];
}
```

Comment: Deberias hacer un arreglo de esa Struct y no poner todos los campos para mostrar lo mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no se como hacer eso para imprimir el valor de de cada variable de una structura.

No se puede, lo que describes se conoce como *introspección* y [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no dispone de ello<sup>1</sup>.

Lo más parecido que puedes hacer es programar tu mismo ese tipo de acceso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

struct Strings {
    std::string Cadena1 = "String 1";
    std::string Cadena2 = "String 2";
    std::string Cadena3 = "String 2";
    std::string Cadena4 = "String 3";
    std::string Cadena5 = "String 4";

    std::string &operator[](unsigned index) { return datos[index]; };

    auto begin() { return std::begin(datos); }
    auto end() { return std::end(datos); }

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<std::string> datos[5] { Cadena1, Cadena2, Cadena3, Cadena4, Cadena5 };
};
```

El código anterior [permite](https://tio.run/##hZHLTsMwEEXX9VeMitQ2UkH0tUlDNnwCy1IhY08jS@048gOQKr49TF40qJXY2ddnxvfOqLK8L5SqqjtD6hg1QmasDw7lKRcXjRVDxVA5RFLBWJLHXAh@jirAS0N5OIuRDzpN2yp4lhpJLuAJxi0Bi/H2FrIcIMvbyOp/ZD1AVreRzQBZM/KXmdgSnQzW7fazSN4UhBoMafxK4AwOQ3QEmgG/a9T9Fr7rHjIGC@9YGJoNwKZzqzY1CdMdi6SvyFq7cKJ05kMGTDuHDg/okBS@fTpZss1sYDzvTG323LMb@rwfbX9Y9Yf1/HcY7L4OYCjASdbuBW@wX6avox2sg5my5AM0zif8I6TgEzFqjSkbA2QZZ3APBQaOxZfpK015/l28R/6lqn4A) el tipo de llamada que buscas:

```
int main()
{
    Strings s;

    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        std::cout << s[i] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Además, al incorporar `begin` y `end` permite también usar el `for` de rango:

```
Strings s;

for (const auto &str : s)
    std::cout << str.get() << '\n';
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Había una propuesta para C++20 de añadir introspección estática, la cuál ha sido retrasada a C++23.

Comment: Muchas gracias Maestro! esto me ayuda muchísimo para reducir mi código

Comment: He compartido una versión más corta.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, voy a aplicar begin y end a mi proyecto